# ngFor - Como puedo mostrar los valores de un arreglo anidado en una tabla

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7

estoy intentando hacer una tabla con angular obteniendo los datos de un arreglo que contiene otros arreglos anidados como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo esta estructura de tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

JSON stringify

```js
[{"name":"Estado 1","series":[{"name":"2021-02-23T06:00:00.000Z","value":"2"},{"name":"2021-02-22T06:00:00.000Z","value":"7"},{"name":"2021-02-19T06:00:00.000Z","value":"1"},{"name":"2021-01-22T06:00:00.000Z","value":"1"},{"name":"2021-01-19T06:00:00.000Z","value":"3"},{"name":"2021-01-12T06:00:00.000Z","value":"1"},{"name":"2021-01-06T06:00:00.000Z","value":"3"}]},{"name":"Estado 2","series":[{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}]}]
```

Y estoy Utilizando un ngFor para recorrer el arreglo y mostrar los datos en una tabla con el siguiente código:

```js
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Fecha<th>
      <th>Estado 1<th>
       <th>Estado 2<th>
        <th>total<th>
   </tr>
 <thead>
</table>
```

```js
 <tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let estado1 of Array[0].series; let i = index">
     <td>{{estado1.name | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</td>
     <td>{{estado1.value}}</td>
   <tr *ngFor="let estado2 of Array[1].series; let i = index">
       <td>{{estado2.name | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</td>
       <td>{{estado2.value}}</td>
       <td>{{estado2.value}} + {{estado1.value}} </td>
     </tr>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Cuando ejecuto este código me da error no me muestra la tabla que quiero hacer, disculpen mi ignorancia no se que estoy haciendo mal o cual es la forma de correcta de recorrer con ngFor con arreglos anidados.

Comment: Hola, aprende a dominar los screenshots si estas en windows puedes utilizar `windows` + `shift` + `s`, puedes [ver este minitutorial](https://www.xataka.com/basics/cuatro-atajos-de-teclado-para-dominar-las-capturas-de-pantalla-en-windows). O puedes descargar [lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/es/). Si editas la pregunta y mejoras esa foto te podemos ayudar rapidamentem

Comment: Hola gracias, ya la edite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te voy a dar una idea, pero es para que la estudies:
NOTA: Yo le puse el nombre TableArray a la variable.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>FECHA</td>
    <td *ngFor="let item of TableArray">{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let series of TableArray[0].series; let i = index">
    <td>{{ series.name | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</td>
    <td>{{ series.value }}</td>
    <td>{{ TableArray[1].series[i].value }}</td>
    <td>{{ +series.value + TableArray[1].series[i].value }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, agregue en la pregunta el tipo de tabla que estoy haciendo

Comment: Como te dice @hawks es mejor ver los datos, no tanto en la imagen, sino mejor en texto. Has el `console.log` pero utiliza el `JSON. stringify` y colocas el texto que te bota, guiate por [Esto](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-log-an-object-to-the-console-in-javascript-7b995c56af5a)

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, ya lo puse que bota con JSON.stringify

Comment: Pero ponlo como texto para poderlo copiar :P, Copia y Pegalo

Comment: ahh perdon xd, ya lo puse xd

Comment: Pero decía que copiaras y pegaras lo que te bota el `JSON.stringify`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127740/discussion-between-alexander-diaz-and-darklawz).

Comment: ya lo puse eso es lo me tira con el JSON stringify

Comment: Ya edite esta respuesta, pero no hago ningun for anidado, solo cambia el nombre de la variable... no se si llama `TableArray` así le puse yo, si no tienes que cambiarla las 4 veces que la utilizo

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, me sirvio

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que verlo como una colección de objetos el array "principal" y luego cada objeto en la propiedad `series` contiene otra lista de objetos.

```javascript
[
 {
    name: "x",
    series: [{...}, {...}, ....] // el ngFor de dentro itera estos datos
 },
 {
    name: "y",
    series: [{...}, {...}, ....]
 },
] // Array de objetos
```

He llamado `items` a la colección de objetos, deberías cambiarla con la variable que tengas en el `component.ts`.

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Fecha</th>
    <th>Estado 1</th>
    <th>Estado 2</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

<tbody>

   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
     <tr *ngFor="let serie of item.series; let j = index">
       <td>{{serie.name | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</td>
       <td>{{serie.value}}</td>
       <td>{{item.series.length}}</td>
     </tr>
   </ng-container>
</tbody>
</table>
```

He actualizado mi respuesta, para adaptarlo a la imagen de la tabla.
La columna (Estado 2) no se que valor debería tener.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, la propiedad value esta dentro de name                            0: name: "fecha"                                                                                                                   
     value: 2

Comment: ahh ok. Te ha servido?

Comment: No me me funciono :(, probé poner <tr *ngFor="let item of items[0].series; let i = index"> con eso si me traer datos pero solo de esa posición

Comment: es muy raro. Por lo que veo en tu template(html) tienes un `<tr>` dentro de `<tr>`. Podria ser por eso?

Comment: Arregle el <Tr>, cuando ejecuto <td>{{item.name | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</td> solo me muestra: 'Estado 1', 'Estado 2', entonces no se si poner algo como item.name.name o item[0].name para acceder a las fechas.

Comment: porque no pones el json entero. Con la imagen no se ven las propiededes. Si es un objeto pues tendras que acceder a la propiedad `item.name.name`

Comment: Volvi a subir la imagen con la propiedades que tiene, habia subido una imagen de mala calidad